# What did Mike Wazowski's paperwork consist of?

Tags: plot-explanation, monsters-inc

There was most likely a good reason for Roz to keep saying

> "*ya didn't file your paperwork last night*".

I'm guessing the paperwork is for accountability and reporting reasons. Mike's responsibility could have been to keep track of the various activities of the workday.

**What did Mike Wazowski's paperwork consist of?**

Answer (score 16):

The quote in the film is

> **Mike:** *The pink copies go to Accounting, the fuchshia ones go to Purchasing,
>   and the goldenrod ones go to Roz. Leave the puce.*

Since the only *consumables* that Mike and Sully use are the doors and the scream containers, we can reasonably assume that the paperwork relates to **the number of doors requested** and **the number of scream containers filled, returned unused or damaged**. There would also be a count of **the amount of scream produced by each door** to allow for forward planning.

Additionally, we see Mike using a stamped door card to call the various doors. 
Those are issued by Roz's office (along with a puce coloured "MI Scare Report"). Since Mike has several of them stored on his desk wall, I think we can assume that they need to be returned to Roz *each time a scare is conducted.*

[image]

[image]

---

Moving away from the film canon, we learn in [Mike's Monstrous Adventure](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Mike's_Monstrous_Adventure) that the yellow (Goldenrod) form is for "Daily **Laugh** Energy". Presumably before it was for "Daily Scream Energy".

[image]

In the film's official [Epic! Graphic Novelisation](https://www.getepic.com/book/17402706/monsters-inc-graphic-novel-disney-), he specially refers to his paperwork as his "***Scare Reports***", lending weight to the idea that they're individualised records of what occurred with each door.

[image]

Comment: The Scare Report copy pictured has a History section, so at a minimum they need to take notes for that on each door.  Seems like doing a Scare Report would be a lot like a doctor updating their charts.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - On the right hand side is a date stamp (like you'd find in a library book) to show when the last scare was. There's a "review by" date on the main form to show when the next door review would be and we see Sulley signing the inside to show that he was the most recent scarer.

Comment: FWIW, the [Albert Lozano](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1145760/) from the pictured report did eventually [become an artist](http://dailytrojan.com/2015/04/14/qa-with-pixar-animator-albert-lozano/). :)

Comment: @JeffBowman  - Which opens up a whole new can of worms about the Pixar Theory